# How to add role to user if user has many companies?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cancancan

In my app users may have many companies, and can have different permissions in companies for crud actions, now i use cancancan gem and authorization look like this:

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :companies, through: :users_companies
  has_many :users_companies
  has_many :users_roles, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :roles, through: :users_roles

  validates :first_name, :last_name, presence: true

  def has_role?(role_sym)
    roles.any? { |r| r.name.underscore.to_sym == role_sym }
  end
end
```

Role.rb

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users_roles
  has_many :users, through: :users_roles
end
```

UsersRole.rb

```
class UsersRole < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role
  #belongs_to :company
end
```

Ability.rb

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # in case of guest
  if user.has_role? :admin
    can :manage, :all
  else
    can :read, :all
  end
  if user.has_role? :moderator
    can :manage, Company
  else
    can :read, :all
  end
    end
end
```

and now when user choose another company user can manage Company model, but doesnt have permission in another company, how to detect company id for user?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct it will help you:

```
can :manage, Company { |company| user.company_id == company.id }
```

And use it:

```
if can? :manage, @company
  # do something
end
```

Comment: thanks user.company_id == company.id in db user model must have column company_id?

Comment: No, you can pass any logic in the block. You can use revert: user.id == company.user_id